# Utilising persuasive language in an email message to generate leads

Tags: email

As part of my thesis, I have to send off "cold surveys" to small-to-medium businesses and individuals in order to collect data. Sadly to date, I've been getting a 1% conversion rate. I think it is primarily down to the way I am structuring my email messages. Is there anything I can do to improve the language of my email message to make them more persuasive? This is what I have so far:

**For individuals**

> Hi Sam,
>
> Sorry to disturb you again.
>
> Just emailing to provide an update – I have finished building an early
>   app prototype as part of my thesis project, using the research data
>   collected as a basis for my design decisions.
>
> It would be great if you could take a look and provide some feedback
>   by next week. All it involves is playing around with the app for a
>   couple of minutes and then filling in a quick survey. Your input will
>   really help with my thesis.
>
> Please let me know if you come across any issues.
>
> Links:
>
> • [Background](http://#)
>
> • [Prototype](http://#)
>
> • [Survey](http://#)
>
> Regards,
>
> Jake Hunter

**For businesses**

> For the management of: Jeanius Clean
>
> I hope that this finds you well.
>
> My name is Jake and I am an undergraduate in Computer Science at
>   Manchester University.
>
> As part of my thesis project, I am carrying out some research into
>   "business attitudes towards the role of intermediary platforms in
>   service provision" in order to test out the [commerciality of an
>   e-commerce solution](http://#), and would really value your contribution to my
>   study.
>
> If you would please take just 2 minutes to answer [this short
>   questionnaire below](http://#) by the end of this week I would be very grateful.
>   All responses are anonymous and results will be kept confidential.
>   Thanks again for your time and support.
>
> Regards,
>
> Jake Hunter

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: This is likely not an issue of language.  The reason that you're getting the cold shoulder to your cold inquiries is that you're imposing on strangers to do work for you.  People are busy, and you're asking them to spend their time on an unknown project for unknown reasons on behalf of an unknown person.  You're asking yourself why they don't help.  You should be asking yourself why they would.

Comment: You offer no incentive beyond earning your "gratitude." As the recipient of several emails like this every week, I've developed a pretty fast "delete" reflex. An apology for disturbing me - Gad! AGAIN!!? - or a wish that this finds me well presages with near certainty that I really won't want to read what's next. "click!” ... history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps http://academia.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the individual email:

- Remove the apologetic introduction. You either ask for their time and thank them, or don't.
- don't dice words - the recipient wants to know what the email is about. Tell them right away that you're asking for help.
- Remove the sentence about using the data to influence design decisions. It's pretty clear from the rest of the email how the data will be used, and that sentence is harder to read, especially after a bunch of long words like prototype.
- put the links after the sign-off - that way it doesnt seem like you're assuming their willingness to participate. It's more respectful.
- provide a brief description of what the app does - that way they may be genuinely interested to try it out rather than regarding it as a chore.

I suggest the following:

> Hi Sam,

I hope this emails finds you well. I'd like to ask you for some help.

I've been building an app for my thesis project, and would like to gather some feedback.

It would really help me if you could try the app and provide some brief comments.

The app is about [this] and allows users to do [that]. Your comments will help me improve the design to make the app better for users. It would be great if you could answer the questionnaire within the next week.

Thanks a lot for your time. I'll let you know how the project develops.

Kind regards,
Jake Hunter

[links]

Comment: Thanks James. Have you got any recommendations for the business email?

Comment: @methuselah I think the difficulty with the business email is that you are not providing a value proposition - there is nothing in it for them. In the individual email you can leverage any existing connections you have with the recipient by appealing to their possible desires to help less experienced people, their desire to be helpful and contribute to building something, or by trying to pique their interest with a description of the app. For the business one, you need to come up with a reason why they would want to help you. Hope this helps!

Comment: What @JamesRoberts said, plus what you are saying, at least to me, is full of jargon unclear on what you're researching. Is it actually how businesses feel about online B2B transactions?